# How do I increase the timeout time when moving large documents between Marklogic clusters?

Tags: ruby, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I keep getting an Internal Server Error while trying to transfer a large document between two MarkLogic clusters. It times out after 5 minutes.

```
SVC-SOCRECV: xdmp:http-post(...) Timeout (decodeResponseLine1)
```

The url looks like this:

```
http://source-host:8020/uri.transfer.xqy?key=/COLLECTION/DB/VeryLargeDoc.xml&srcdb=DB&destdb=DB&desthost=dest-host
```

I've tried to set the timeout to 10 minutes with `xdmp:set-request-time-limit(600)` in the function. The xquery function:

```
declare function my-ns:transfer-records(
    $record as element(record),
    $database as xs:string,
    $host as xs:string)
{
  let $response :=
    xdmp:set-request-time-limit(600,
    xdmp:http-post("http://" || $host || ":" || $PORT || "/doc_transfer.xqy?database=" || $database,
        <options xmlns="xdmp:http">
            <headers>
                <content-type>application/gzip</content-type>
            </headers>
        </options>,
        xdmp:gzip($record)
    )
  )
  return
    xdmp:set-response-code($response[1]//*:code, $response[1]//*:message)
};
```

This is not working. Where should I modify the timeout. The timeout appears to be happening on the source-host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple timeouts that could bother you:

- Keep the [`xdmp:set-request-time-limit`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:set-request-time-limit), or MarkLogic might impatiently kill the entire statement if the http-post is too slow.
- Add a `<timeout>` to the `xdmp:http-post` [options](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:http-get) to make sure http-post won't cancel the request client-side. The default value is the http timeout for the group. (note: the SVC-SOCRECV seems to indicate this is what is happening)
- Also make sure the server-side time limit is large enough. There will be code running server-side to write whatever you are sending. It will be constrained by the `default time limit`, unless `doc_transfer.xqy` contains an explicit `xdmp:set-request-time-limit` as well.

HTH!

Comment: If you read the docs for xdmp:http-post carefully, you'll see it accepts the same options as xdmp:http-get plus one more..

Comment: Http-post does support timeout option. I know the link points to http-get. That is intentional, because that is where the option is described..

Comment: "The other options are the same as the other xdmp:http-* functions, and the options are documented with the xdmp:http-get $options parameter." Good call @grtjn !

Answer (score 0):

For those who may want to see a solution for this that worked. (Thanks to @grtjn) I added a `<timeout>900</timeout>` element which sets the timeout to 900 seconds. The default is 300 seconds in this group on this cluster for me.

```
declare function my-ns:transfer-records(
    $record as element(record),
    $database as xs:string,
    $host as xs:string)
{
  let $response :=
    xdmp:set-request-time-limit(600,
    xdmp:http-post("http://" || $host || ":" || $PORT || "/doc_transfer.xqy?database=" || $database,
        <options xmlns="xdmp:http">
            <headers>
                <content-type>application/gzip</content-type>
            </headers>
            <timeout>900</timeout>
        </options>,
        xdmp:gzip($record)
    )
  )
  return
    xdmp:set-response-code($response[1]//*:code, $response[1]//*:message)
};
```